# Wide ball gone to boundary by touching Keeper's Helmet

Tags: rules, cricket

I was watching a Domestic T20 tournament. One interesting thing happened during the match, where a Fast Bowler bowled a wide ball, which easily crossed boundary roaps, but interestingly by touching the wicket-keeper's helmet which was on the ground behind the wicket-keeper.

Runs awarded in this case are, 5 PEN+1(Wide), Four ignored.

What ICC Rules explain in this?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by [Law 41.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/):

> If a protective helmet belonging to the fielding side is on the ground within the field of play, and the ball while in play strikes it, **the ball shall become dead** and [...] 5 penalty runs shall then be awarded to the batting side, in addition to the penalty for a No ball or a Wide, if applicable.

(my emphasis). As the ball becomes dead when it hits the helmet, the fact it runs away to the boundary is unimportant - play stops when the ball hits the helmet.

Comment: The rule you linked to now redirects to law 28. Also, it clearly mentions that the helmet can be kept behind the wicketkeeper. (" Protective helmets, when not in use by fielders, may not be placed on the ground, above the surface **except behind the wicket-keeper and in line with both sets of stumps.**") So, I think penalty should not be awarded here. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. The Law very clearly states the penalty is applied if the ball hits the helmet.

Comment: 28.3.2 says that "If the ball while in play strikes a helmet, **placed as described in 28.3.1**, ..., an award of 5 Penalty runs shall be made to the batting side" and the law 28.3.1 _excludes_ an helmet placed behind the wicketkeeper. So I still don't see the fault.